# Keyboard "Enter" button is not calculating value

Tags: javascript, product-view

[here](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html)  when we enter zip code [110001] & click on "**check**"
button through "mouse" its displaying shipping charges above "ADD TO CART" button.

but when we entered zip code and press "Enter" button from keyboard, than its not calcualting shipping charges.

we are using following code to find shipping charges :

**phtml**

```
<input placeholder="Enter your PIN Code" class="input-text validate-postcode<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?> 
required-entry<?php endif;?>" type="text" id="estimate_postcode" name="estimate[postcode]" 
value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('postcode')) ?>" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}" />
```

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function estimateProductShipping()
{
    var estimationUrl = '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getEstimateUrl());?>';
    var items = $$(['.shipping-estimation-form input',
                    '.shipping-estimation-form select',
                    '#product_addtocart_form input',
                    '#product_addtocart_form select']);

    var validationResult = true;

    // Check the valid input
    if (!items.map(Validation.validate).all()) {
        return;
    }

    var parameters = Form.serializeElements(items, true);
    $('shipping-estimate-loading-message').show();
    $('shipping-estimate-results').hide();
    new Ajax.Updater('shipping-estimate-results', estimationUrl, {
        parameters: parameters,
        onComplete: function() {
            $('shipping-estimate-loading-message').hide();
            $('shipping-estimate-results').show();
        }
    });

}
//]]>
</script>
```

I am trying following script. but its not working :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function estimateProductShipping()
{
    var estimationUrl = '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getEstimateUrl());?>';
    var items = $$(['.shipping-estimation-form input',
                    '.shipping-estimation-form select',
                    '#product_addtocart_form input',
                    '#product_addtocart_form select']);

    var validationResult = true;

    // Check the valid input
    if (!items.map(Validation.validate).all()) {
        return;
    }

    var parameters = Form.serializeElements(items, true);
    $('shipping-estimate-loading-message').show();
    $('shipping-estimate-results').hide();

    document.getElementById('zipcode').onkeypress = function(e){
        if (!e) e = window.event;
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == '13'){


    new Ajax.Updater('shipping-estimate-results', estimationUrl, {
        parameters: parameters,
        onComplete: function() {
            $('shipping-estimate-loading-message').hide();
            $('shipping-estimate-results').show();
        }

        }
    });
    }
 }  
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: does it even get to the getelementbyid.onkeypress function? you can check if you add a console.log or alert right after.. then you can continue checking until you get to where it goes wrong.

Comment: i didt added console.log or alert, please post an answer with updated code for adding alert & console.log, so that i will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            ( function($) {
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#estimate_postcode').keydown(function(e){
                        var items = $$(['.shipping-estimation-form input',
                                        '.shipping-estimation-form select',
                                        '#product_addtocart_form input',
                                        '#product_addtocart_form select']);
                        var estimationUrl = '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getEstimateUrl());?>';
                        var parameters = Form.serializeElements(items, true);
                        console.log("zipcode onkeypress worked");
                        if (!e) e = window.event;
                        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
                        if (keyCode == '13'){
                          //disable default enter action
                            e.preventDefault(); 
                            console.log("Enter button was pressed");
                            $('#shipping-estimate-loading-message').show();
                            $('#shipping-estimate-results').hide(); 

                           new Ajax.Updater('shipping-estimate-results', estimationUrl, {
                               parameters: parameters,
                               onComplete: function() {
                                  console.log("ajax updater worked");
                                  $('#shipping-estimate-loading-message').hide();
                                  $('#shipping-estimate-results').show();
                               }    
                           });
                       };
                   });
                });
            } ) ( jQuery );

                function estimateProductShipping()
                {
                    var estimationUrl = '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getEstimateUrl());?>';
                    var items = $$(['.shipping-estimation-form input',
                                    '.shipping-estimation-form select',
                                    '#product_addtocart_form input',
                                    '#product_addtocart_form select']);

                    var validationResult = true;

                    // Check the valid input
                    if (!items.map(Validation.validate).all()) {
                        return;
                    }

                    var parameters = Form.serializeElements(items, true);

                    $('shipping-estimate-loading-message').show();
                    $('shipping-estimate-results').hide();   


                   new Ajax.Updater('shipping-estimate-results', estimationUrl, {
                        parameters: parameters,
                        onComplete: function() {
                           console.log("ajax updater worked");
                           $('shipping-estimate-loading-message').hide();
                           $('shipping-estimate-results').show();
                        }    
                    });
                }
//]]>
</script>
```

Now you *should* see 3 logging messages in your developer console. also I added a preventDefault() to your e variable, maybe that's where it goes wrong?

Comment: please check the  [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-keychain.html) now

Comment: now i am not getting shipping charges if i click  on "check" button.

Comment: try wrapping the code with  jQuery(document).ready(function(){ }. if you check the console, it tells you estimateProductShipping is not defined

Comment: i added code like this : http://pastebin.com/niCVX44Y , correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: does it show any error in the console if you use that?

Comment: I edited code, see if that works

Comment: visit [here](http://hotwheelstoys.in/3/em0113-full-package/index.php/electronics/nokia-2610-phone.html)

i am gettting console errors as in image : http://prnt.sc/ajrbis

Comment: i updated your code, but still when we click on "check" button ,its not calculating shipping charges.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37508/discussion-between-anja-and-baby-in-magento).

Answer (score 1):

You should use like below code:

```
$jQuery("#estimate_postcode").keyup(function(event) {   
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        alert('enter');
// work there
    }
});
```

Comment: okay i will try as you said.

Answer (score 1):

remove `onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}"` from the input.

Comment: I removed the code, now when we enter zip code [110001] & press enter button from key board, its redirecting

to shopping cart.